# Xpath Date Comparison using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

i have xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test1.xsl"?>
<products>
    <node>
        <node>
            <dist_value>
            <node> 55 </node>
            <node> 59 </node>
            <node> 72 </node>
            </dist_value>
            <reg_str_dt>
            <node> 2013-08-03 17:29:00 </node>
            </reg_str_dt>
            <product_id> 1 </product_id>
        </node>
    </node>
    <node>
        <node>
            <dist_value>
            <node> 72 </node>
            <node> 19 </node>
            <node> 49 </node>
            </dist_value>
            <reg_str_dt>
            <node> 2013-10-25 17:29:00 </node>
            </reg_str_dt>
            <product_id> 2 </product_id>
        </node>
    </node> 
    <node>
        <node>
            <dist_value>
            <node> 12 </node>
            <node> 548 </node>
            <node> 112 </node>
            </dist_value>
            <reg_str_dt>
            <node> 2013-08-12 17:29:00 </node>
            </reg_str_dt>
            <name> test </name>
            <product_id> 3 </product_id>
        </node>
    </node>
</products>
```

i have written this PHP code to compare the date

```
$my_date = '2013-09-01';
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('product.xml');
$xpd = new DOMXPath($xml);
false&&$result_data = new DOMElement();
$result = $xpd->query("//node[reg_str_dt[(translate(node,'-','') > translate($my_date, '-', '') ]/*");
foreach($result as $result_data){
    echo $result_data->nodeName ." => ". $result_data->nodeValue ."<br/>";
}
```

but this code is not working

in output it will return the data of product 2

Comment: I actually wonder why you think it *could* work at all. It's not the proper way to compare strings nor numbers (as there ain't no numbers no) in xpath.

Answer (score 2):

try this its work:-

```
<?php
$my_date = '2013-09-01';
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('product.xml');
$xpd = new DOMXPath($xml);
false&&$result_data = new DOMElement();
$result = $xpd->query('//node[translate(translate(translate("2013-09-01 17:20:19", "-", "")," ",""),":","") > translate(translate(translate(node/reg_str_dt/node,"-","")," ",""),":","")]/*');
foreach($result as $result_data){
    echo $result_data->nodeName." => ". $result_data->nodeValue ."<br/>";;
}
?>
```